# Total Contiguous Days. How can I know if Date+1 exists?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Ive a table with dates of absence per day and type of absences. How can I find total of contiguous days for an absence e.g. Illness.

Ive tried with `DCount` but it's ok with 10 records but with 400 records very very slow:

```
sSQL = "[Employee Number] = " & nP & " And [Leave] = """ & lve & """ And [Date_Leave] = #" & Format(DateAdd("d", n, d1), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#"
If Nz(DCount("*", "Employee_Data", sSQL)) = 0 Then
            nbJ = n
```

How can I replace `DCount` with a DAO code?

Comment: Some sample data with the expected result would be helpful.

Comment: 400 records is not much and should not be slow. I use domain aggregate on tables with thousands of records and performance is not slow.

Comment: Open the table/query as a recordset in VBA using DAO and loop the records. As long as the current date equals the preceding date plus one, you have a contiguous range. From here, it is unclear what you wish to do with such a range, if a range can be one day, or if a new range starts or ends something.

Comment: You also don't mention workdays. If I normally work Monday through Friday and I'm off sick Thursday, Friday, and the following Monday then that would presumably count as three consecutive workdays even though the calendar days are not consecutive.